# jQuery hiding/showing sections based on .index()

Tags: jquery

I have 3 titles that when clicked they have their own description. I only want the description that matches to the title to be displayed.

```js
$('.descriptions p').hide();

$('.titles h3').click(function() {
  var a = $(this).index();
  
  ('.descriptions p').index(a).fadeIn();
})
```

```css
.titles h3 {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="titles">
  <h3>Title One</h3>
  <h3>Title Two</h3>
  <h3>Title Three</h3>
</div>

<div class="descriptions">
  <p>Description One</p>
  <p>Description Two</p>
  <p>Description Three</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had some little mistakes.

### .index() vs .eq()

> The .eq() function returns the object at the specified location in the array returned by the jQuery selector.

---

> The .index() function takes a jQuery selector as parameter. This function is run on something that is already a jquery/DOM Element. Based on the selector passed to .index() jQuery will determine what the index is of the DOM element it was run on.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/gsnr99he/) is the corrected code.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.descriptions p').hide();

    $('.titles h3').click(function () {
        var a = $(this).index();

        $('.descriptions p').eq(a).fadeIn();
    })
});
```

```css
.titles h3 {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="titles">
     <h3>Title One</h3>
     <h3>Title Two</h3>
     <h3>Title Three</h3>

</div>
<div class="descriptions">
    <p>Description One</p>
    <p>Description Two</p>
    <p>Description Three</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is it `eq()` instead of `index()`?